# Problem to set up xamarin iOS Hot Restart

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I want do debug my xamarin app on my iPhone SE (real device).
For this I signed up for apple dev club and already paid it.
I have my mac with xcode 13 running in the network and I am able to connect VS with the mac.

Now when I try to launch the app with Hot Restart I am asked to give my apple credentials and have to select my team, no problem..
But after selecting team it gets an error telling me I should check protocols but I don't know what to do here... (Please have a look at the image)

I already imported the Provisioning and the certs to xcode.

Using VS 17.2.3 on Win11, macOS 12.4 and it is a xamarin forms app

[image: visual studio error]

Comment: Please add to question the English translation of the error message. (As text, instead of an image.)

Comment: "An attempt to automatically deploy the project failed. Check the logs"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,there are a few issues with provisioning (both automatic and manual) for [Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart).

The issue is being track in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-load-Apple-certificates/1692185) in developer community,please follow up the issue in that [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-load-Apple-certificates/1692185).